# Unknown modifier while using preg_quote() in preg_match_all()

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am having a problem with my `preg_match_all()` function.
I have a string e.g.

```
$string = '<div id="header">Hello</div>'
preg_match_all('/'.preg_quote('<div id="header">').'(.*?)'.preg_quote('</end>').'/s', $string, $matches);
```

And I am looking to get the output `Hello`.

But I only get this error:

> preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'd' in C:\xampp\htdocs\classes\Functions.php on line 13

Comment: So where are we with this question ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the delimiter for [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php), so just add the delimiter as a second argument, like this:

```
preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote('<div id="header">' , "/") . '(.*?)' . preg_quote('</end>', "/") . '/s', $string, $matches);
                                                    //^^^                                   ^^^
```